# How to find and select element between tags in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, html, selenium-chromedriver

This is my bot.py code:

```
from config import keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time


def order(k):

    driver= webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")



    driver.get(k['product_url'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-categories"]/li[5]/a').click()
    AElements=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for el in AElements:
       if el.text == 'Magenta':
           AElements.click()

    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cart"]/a[2]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="order_billing_name"]').send_keys(k["name"])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="order_email"]').send_keys(k["email"])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="order_tel"]').send_keys(k["phone_number"])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bo"]').send_keys(k["address"])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="order_billing_city"]').send_keys(k["city"])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="order_billing_zip"]').send_keys(k["code"])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cnb"]').send_keys(k["card_number"])
    #month
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="credit_card_month"]/option[{}]").format(k['card_exp_mo']).click()
    #year
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="credit_card_year"]/option[{}]").format(k["card_exp_yr"]).click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vval"]').send_keys(k["cvv_code"])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="order_billing_country"]/option[26]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[ @ id = "cart-cc"] / fieldset / p / label / div / ins').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pay"]/input').click()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    order(keys)
```

I want to choose a element which is shows in HTML as:

```
<a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/tzdwbk5pg/dptqdojbx">Magenta</a>
```

Magenta is the text which I want to choose maybe someone wants to help me please

In Terminal I see it 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's also a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong inside your `for loop`, it should `el.click()` not `AElements.click()`:

```
AElements=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for el in AElements:
    if el.text == 'Magenta':
        el.click()
        #if you want break
        break
```